# javascript - hightlight selected text in different divs

Tags: javascript

I have 2 divs and I want to highlight the text I select no matter what div holds it.

I tried using `div` instead of `span` but didn't give me the result I wanted.

Code:

```js
function setColor() {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
    span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = 'highlight';
  span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
  range.insertNode(span);
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: rgba(250, 166, 26, .2);
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Div 1 text
</div>
<div>
  Div 2 text
</div>
<button onClick="setColor()">Apply color</button>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't seem to see an issue while testing your code.

Comment: Can you make demo of jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I want to apply the highlight like... multiline, but instead of using `br` I'm dealing with divs

Comment: If you want just to change the color, use CSS's `::selection`!

Comment: I don't want [this](http://nirewen.s-ul.eu/7WsdcQ8i.gif) to happen

Comment: Did you try [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)?